# how to count the longest sequence of the same value in a list of lists, and then output the largest sequence in a tuple

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of lists 9in a text file) with values similar to what is below:

```
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
def longest_sequence(l):
        counter = 0
        sl = []
        sublists = []
        for i in l:
            if (l[counter+1]==l[counter]):
                sl.append(l[counter])
                counter = counter + 1
            else:
                counter = 0
                sublists.append([sl[i], len(sl)])
        return sublists
```

Right now counts only one value in this case the one that appears first (1) then it goes to the next line which is similar a sequence and the output i'm getting is this one:

```
returns the sub lists [[1, 111], [1, 222], [1, 333], [1, 444], [1, 555], [1, 666], [1, 777], [1, 888]]
```

basically what I'm trying to do is checking the list and from that list verifying which sub-list has the longest length, so I should be getting something like this instead:

```
sl = [(1, 111), (0, 395), (1, 65), (2, 358), (1, 71)]
```

Being the second tuple the one returned as ti contains the value that got repeated continuously 395 times (longest length) among all sub lists.

Comment: So you are trying to find the longest list compared to the list found in each text file?

Comment: No, I'm trying to check the length of each sub list in a list like the one above and return the value that was repeated the most among sublists, so it should give me the length of that sub list and the value in that sublist. the values only vary between 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: What you posted as an example is just a single list with no sublists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this simply with `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

[(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in it.groupby(L)]
# [(k, len(list(g)) for k, g in it.groupby(L)]  # alternative

Out[]:
[(1, 112), (0, 394), (1, 65), (2, 359), (1, 71)]
```

To get the maximum, you can use `max()` with a `key`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import operator as op

counts = [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in it.groupby(L)]
max(counts, key=op.itemgetter(1))

Out[]:
(0, 394)
```

However, fixing your code.

- You are confusing your indexing (`counter`), when you reset it in the `else:` block you start from the beginning again. Just use `range(1, len(l))` in your `for` loop for the index.
- You don't reset `sl` in the `else:` block (hence it keeps growing by `111`) but you really don't need to create the `sl` list just count the items
- You miss the case of the last value
- Dealing with the last value needs a little reordering of logic

So fixed, it would look like:

```
def longest_sequence(l):
    counter = 1
    sublists = []
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[i] != l[i-1]:
            sublists.append([l[i-1], counter])
            counter = 0
        counter += 1

    if counter > 0:
        sublists.append((l[i], counter))

    return sublists

In []:
longest_sequence(L)

Out[]:
[(1, 112), (0, 394), (1, 65), (2, 359), (1, 71)]

In []:
max(longest_sequence(L), key=op.itemgetter(1))

Out[]:
(0, 394)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but then there is only one part I'm missing. at the end I will only need the tuple that contains the longest sequence which in this case it will be (0, 394) is it just simple to compare the second value of each tuple in that sublist?

Comment: I tried this code: import operator as op

counts = [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in it.groupby(L)]
max(counts, key=op.itemgetter(1))

Out[]:
(0, 394) and at least in my case the output I get is: ([1, 112], 1)...

Comment: print out `counts` and see if you are seeing the pairs you expect. It looks like you have picked up and extra `tuple` value. Which you shouldn't get with the above code.

Comment: I'll show you: when I print the statement assigned to counts, this is what I get  [([1, 112], 1), ([0, 394], 1), ([1, 65], 1), ([2, 359], 1), ((1, 71), 1)]  then if continue with the line of max I get this: ([1, 112], 1)

Comment: done, I was doing it wrong that's why I got those values, but now is as the answer you get :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) algorithm.  Example tool from the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library:

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit    


list(mit.run_length.encode(L))
# [(1, 112), (0, 394), (1, 65), (2, 359), (1, 71)]
```

---

**Details**

The [`.encode`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.run_length) method returns the equivalent of following generator expression:

```
((k, ilen(g)) for k, g in groupby(iterable))
```

You can optionally use the `.decode` method to get back the original list.

Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.